# Peculiar and inconsistent behaviour of compose-key after reboot. How should I troubleshoot?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, reboot, troubleshooting, compose-key

On my Linux Mint 19.3 - Cinnamon, I have observed that sometimes the compose-key works, sometimes it doesn't. Especially, it stopped working after reboot.

Investigating it led me to the conclusions that

1. it does **NOT ALWAYS** stop working after reboot.
2. **it comes back after switching back from a v-term** (Ctrl-Alt-F1, then [Ctrl-]Alt-F7)
3. Killing (and auto restarting) cinnamon-session doesn't seem to make problem re-appear

a friend of mine tested it on his Ubuntu 20.4 - Mate and didn't observe this problem. I don't know if the problem might be related with Linux Mint or with Cinnamon

Any lead on what else I could try to investigate this ?

Comment: Check udev rules/udev hw database. Check systemd startup order, it's not deterministic, which would cause the "sometimes works, sometimes doesn't".